# Fragment и DialogFragment с DatePickerDialog внутри проблемка

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment, dialogfragment

Вообщем есть у меня фрагмент, который отображает курсы валют за выбранную дату. Дату я выбираю с помощью `DialogFragment` с `DatePickerDialog` внутри.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.setTargetFragment(HistoryCurrencyFragment.this, DatePickerFragment.REQUEST_CODE);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker"); 
}
```

после этого в `DatePickerFragment` в методе `onDateSet` я передаю выбранную дату в свой первый фрагмент

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    HistoryCurrencyFragment.getInstance().setDate(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);
}
```

поле этого в методе `setDate` класса `HistoryCurrencyFragment` я запускаю асинктаск.

```
public void setDate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    new HistoryCurrencyAsync(dayOfMonth + "." + monthOfYear + "." + year).execute();
}
```

после того как получаю данные я помощью кастомного адаптера сетаю в лист вью.
только проблема вот в чем после того как я возвращаюсь с `DatePickerFragment`  в фрагмент в котором все должно отображаться HistoryCurrencyFragment  то адаптер и листвью `null`.

Я инициализировал их в методе onCreate там указывал `setRetainInstance(true);` что бы фрагмент не пересоздавался. и пробовал в методе `onPostExecute` в асинктаске инициализировать все равно `null`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    listAdapterHistory = new ListAdapterHistory(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), currencyLists);
    listView = new ListView(getContext());
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapterHistory);
}
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Currency> currencies) {
    super.onPostExecute(currencies);
    Log.e("Kурс валют за " + date + " size: " + currencies.size(), "onPostExecute");
    currencyLists = currencies;
    Log.e("!!!!!!!!adapter!!!!!!!", "onPostExecute " + listAdapterHistory);
    Log.e("!!!!!!!!list!!!!!!", "onPostExecute" + currencyLists.size());
    Log.e("!!!!!!!listview!!!!!!!", "onPostExecute" + listView);
    listAdapterHistory.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

---

```
E/!!!!!!!!adapter!!!!!!!: onPostExecute null
E/!!!!!!!!list!!!!!!: onPostExecute20
E/!!!!!!!listview!!!!!!!: onPostExecutenull
```

не могу понять в чем проблема помогите пожалуйста

`null` они становятся тогда когда я возвращаюсь с `DialogFragment` в первый фрагмент.

Comment: Вот здесь `HistoryCurrencyFragment.getInstance().setDate(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);` Вы создаете **новый** фрагмент и передаете ему значения. Поэтому и получается, что у этого фрагмента поля нулевые, так как, вообще говоря, он не привязан к активити.

Comment: Да, ты прав.
ошибка была именно  в этом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь:

```
HistoryCurrencyFragment.getInstance().setDate(year,monthOfYe‌​ar,dayOfMonth);
```

Вы создаете новый фрагмент и передаете ему значения. Поэтому и получается, что у этого фрагмента поля нулевые, так как, вообще говоря, он не привязан к активити.